# Load asset file inside page template with Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a page, `ContentPage`, that shows the contents of a static file of my app. The html file of my page is the following (`content.html`):

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{ lessonNumber }} - {{ pageNumber }}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <!-- TXT CONTENT GOES HERE -->
  {{ txtContent }}

</ion-content>
```

My static files are under `src/assets/txts/`

```
src
|_ app
|_ assets
   |_ txts
      |_ 1.txt
      |_ 2.txt
      |_ 3.txt
      |_ ...
|_ pages
|_ ...
```

When the `ContentPage` is open I need to get one of the txt files, such as `1.txt`, and load his contents inside the `content.html` page.

This is my page code:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {IonicPage} from "ionic-angular";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-content',
  templateUrl: 'content.html',
})
export class ContentPage {

  lessonNumber: number;
  pageNumber: number;

  txtContent: string = '';

  constructor() {
    //FIXME - get txt contents
    //txtContent = ...
  }

}
```

How can I do that?

Is there a class or plugin that allows me to get these files?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `HTTP` request get the data from txt file. you can write in constructor or service

```
constructor() {
    this.http.request('./txt/1.txt')
                     .map(res => res.text()    })
          .subscribe(text => {
            this.txtContent= text;
          });
 }
```

Comment: There are some typos in this. where is the matching `{` for the hanging `}`?